# Injecting class name and toggling class name Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I am aware that in angular you can do something like this:

```
<div ng-class="{myClassName: myCondition}"></div>
```

and Angular will add 'myClassName' to the class attribute if the condition is true.

I am also aware that:

```
<div ng-class="myClassName"></div>
```

will evaluate my 'myClassName' scope value and add it to the element's class argument.

Is there a way to do both of these at the same time on an element? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you right,

```
<div ng-class="{myClassName: true}" class="{{myOtherClassName}}"></div>
```

*controller*

```
 $scope.myOtherClassName = "someClass";
```

The result should be:

```
<div   class="someClass myClassName"></div>
```

Comment: Isn't it `{{myOtherClassName}}`?

Comment: Yes but if you do that and you also have another class declared you get spaces in your markup when myOtherClassName is undefined.
Not sure if it's that big of a problem though. I was just curious if they had planned for that and provided a way to get around it.